# Dynamic php variable in mysql INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, bulkinsert

I am taking values from my form that has `39 fields`, all fields have name's order as

```
field1,field2,field3 .......
```

and my sql table `mytable` also have 39 fields with the same name i.e.     `field1,field2,field3 .......`

Now in the submit.php I am looking for a solution where I don't want to write all these 39 variables to store in `mytable` i.e. `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(field1,field2,field3,......)`

But I am looking for a solution in which I don't have to write all these 39 variables and still  I can store them in different 39 fields of sql. What I've tried is:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (
".
for ($k=1; $k<=39; $k++)
{

$vari=$_POST["field".$k];   


$Temp_previous_total++;

}
.")");
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? Is it why your example code didn't work, for which there a various reasons :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myvars = '';
for ($k=1; $k<=39; $k++)
{
   $myvars .= "'".$_POST["field".$k]."',";   
}
$myvars = substr($myvars,0,-1);
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (
".$myvars.")";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: This is how your code should work. But keep in mind this is very bad practice as mentioned by keeg

Comment: @JonStirling there are commas separating in the for loop?

Comment: Ugh, talk about me getting the wrong end of the stick with my last comment :/. Anyway, might be worth assuming that the OPs fields are actually text inputs and quote accordingly but meh, it's not specifically an issue without more context.

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 , I counted both of them are 39 39

Comment: @Programer Do: var_dump($query) and post how the query looks like.

Comment: @Programer I also updated the code to reflect the quotes suggested by Jon, try if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely sanitize those fields before you insert them, here is a really helpful class for mysql queries: [PHP MySQL wrapper v3](http://www.ricocheting.com/code/php/mysql-database-class-wrapper-v3) that does exactly that